# Visual studio 2017 debugging runs slow when locals\watch window is open

Tags: .net, visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS2017 community developing projects in .net.
When debugging it takes up to 10 sec to jump from line to line when the locals or watch windows is open (if i close it debug looks normal), now I understand that the computer has more things to do when those windows are open but 10 second from line to line is terrible (most lines don't even change the variables). looking back this behavior started in VS2015, before that I ran VS2010 and VS2008 which worked OK. can this be related to the fact that I'm using community version? (with 2008 and 2010 i ran pro version)

Comment: How many / complex variables are we talking about? I'd imagine the performance to depend on the amount of memory to be watched rather than the amount of actual changes.

Comment: not that many, the problem start even if i'm at the begin of the program where there are less then 10 variables. never mind the fact that this wasn't an issue in VS2010 on the same exact code.

Comment: Surely nothing that a disk reformat could not fix.  Consider killing off some usually-less-than-helpful processes if that doesn't sound attractive, start with the anti-malware.  And disable the Diagnostics Tools, they are a litter bug that can spam the Temp directory badly.

Comment: that's funny cause I installed VS2017 on a new computer so no format is needed :). anti-malware is unlikely since we see that the performance is deeply linked to the locals/watch window nothing outside of VS affects it, also I run a pretty tight ship.

Comment: Maybe the spectre/meltdown updates destroyed performance... it seems they have a broad and bad impact on the *inspect a program from aside* like tools (but that's really just a wild far fetched guess, because those patches [completely bricked CPU sampling on many VS versions](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/177958/starting-the-profiler-leads-to-computer-restart-af.html))

Comment: Very interesting but I don't think so, since that problem started awhile ago I've been using VS2015 for almost 2 years and updated to 2017 a few months ago. Prior to that using VS2010 and 2008 didn't had that problem.

Comment: Can this be related to the fact that I'm using VS community and not professional?

Comment: I think most people will stick to one or the other version for some time... so if you want a yes/no question to comparison of VS versions, how about you try it yourself with the Trial version of VS 2017 Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is because of a **Realtime scan in Antivirus**

**Add exceptions** for Visual Studio's files/folders in the Antivirus

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017
```